# Blocking Users From finding Links

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, html5-video

I have a video i'm storing on my server.

I dont want people to be able to link to that video after finding the link (view source).

What is the best way to handle such a situation?

Thanks,
Danny

Comment: easy: don't store it on you server and publish it!

Comment: I would say: you should not prevent users from doing that. But __if you really need to__, then technical possibilities are interesting. In any case there is no 100% reliable method, I believe. Or maybe it is, but is very costly, and in most cases would _make users angry_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to *encrypt* the link somehow, if you do not want (or cannot) use authentication, what was suggested by John in his answer. If your link would change every hour, sharing would be difficult.

If you use something like md5 hash from the current hour (and day), then any discovered link would be unusable after approximately two hours. Why two? Because you should handle the situation when the link is generated at 12:59:59, so when the client's browser tries to access the resource, the link is invalid. To prevent that situation you should check whether the *previous* hour matches the url, if the current hour does not.

If using a hash in URL is too difficult, you may require the parameter - and use the code similar to that shown by John in his answer.

*So, the scenario looks like this*:

The client fetches a page. Your server needs to put there a link to the video. It checks that it's `2012-06-29 14:55:30`, takes that date as something like `2012-06-29T14:5_:__` calculates a hash, and comes up with URL like this: `href="/videos/736453273dh367d52gs82/movie.mpg"`

The client's browser downloads the resource, so your server receives a request for that URL with these strange numbers inside. Your server checks the time, and finds that it is `2012-06-29 14:55:31`. Clears the last three digits (because I think that an hour may be too much), and creates a hash from `2012-06-29T14:5_:__`. Does it match the URL provided by the client? Yes. Then serve the file.

If the URL does not match, then the server decreases the time by one, so it tries to encode `2012-06-29T14:4_:__` - if that also does not match, returns the error code.

Thus you have links which work only for ~20 minutes. You may decide what time range is good for your needs. But remember - anyone who got that link will be able to use it during that time. Also be careful with what you get to generate that hash - if that will be only the time, you risk that that scheme will be guessable. Use some random *salt*, but remember that it has to be the same for the page which *generates* the URL and the page which *checks* the URL.

Comment: What stops someone using curl to get all the parameters, session, cookies, hashes, setting useragent and referrer. required to download... zip

Comment: If the link is valid only in some time-frame, it does not require any session parameters. This method requires only the _time_ on the server. But if I download the resource and publish it myself... Nobody can stop me :) I also think that in most cases these prevent-sharing techniques are bad. Bad for the usability, I mean.

Answer (score 4):

Don't store it in your web root. Keep it outside of your web root and refer to it via a PHP file. That file will authenticate the user to verify that you want them to be able to view the video and allow them to see it. Otherwise it will prevent the video from loading or load an error message instead.

HTML:

```
<a href="video.php">Watch the video</a>
```

Sample PHP (video.php):

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['authenticated']))
    {
        exit;
    }
    $file = '/path/to/file/outside/www/secret.avi';

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: hm, so the user has to  authenticate... how do you prevent the user from sharing the link + his credentials?

Comment: You can try to do IP checking, etc. But the bottom line is there is no 100% foolproof way to stop someone from viewing the video that you don't want to have access to it. If it's on the Internet, it's ultimately available to everyone if they're willing to try hard enough to get it.

Comment: The above code would also not allow files over 2gb or handle progressive loading. the right answer is: `Q:Blocking Users From finding Links` `A: You cant`

Comment: Thanks, very nice thinking...!

Answer (score 2):

You might haven't phrased your question correctly, but I think that what you're looking for is hot-linking prevention, add this to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(avi|mp4)$ - [F]
```

a more effective way would be to use one-time links:

- The page hosting the video is requested.
- Generate a random string and store it in a session and append it to the link `video.php?id=10&token=9283y540983y45
- Use John Conde's method to restrict direct access and allow access via .php file.
- In the PHP file check if the token in the URL is correct by comparing to the string in the session.

Comment: That would not work, because I can add that header to `wget` and download the file without problem.

Comment: @Arsen7, well you don't even need `wget` for that. No matter what you do, if you don't use one-time links, your links WILL be shared and WILL be used in a way you don't want to.